# matlab: multidimensional array names

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a 3-by-4-by-5 matrix, and I want to give names to the third dimension `['a','b','c','d','e']`. How do I do this? The `dataset` command only seems to work for matrices?

Comment: Just a note on your "string array", `['a','b','c','d','e']` is exactly the same as `'abcde'`. You need to use cell array to generate a string array: `{'a','b','c','d','e'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your 3D array into a cell array of matrices, and then convert this cell array to a struct with the desired field names:

```
x = rand(3,4,5); % example input
y = num2cell(x, [1 2]); % to cell of matrices spanning the first and second dims
y = cell2struct(y, {'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'}, 3); % to struct with desired field names
```

Then you can refer to the matrices as `y.a`, `y.b` etc:

```
>> isequal(y.b, x(:,:,2)) % check
ans =
  logical
   1
```

Note, however, that keeping the data as a 3D array is usually faster and more efficient. So an alternative would be to define the desired "names" by means of constants `A = 1`, `B = 2` etc, and index into the original 3D array as `x(:,:,A)`, `x(:,:,B)`.